# Should I put reading group coordination / participation on CV?

Tags: cv, extracurricular

I am an active participant in an academic reading group. I am co-coordinator, meaning I help pick topics, schedule talks, coordinate food, update the website, send emails, etc. I've also presented a couple times when we can't get presenters at the last minute. I think a link on my website is fine, but does this activity warrant a place on an academic CV?

(EDIT: I'm a second-year PhD student if that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely yes. This is an important and cool activity. You can write something like:

*2016-18 Coordinator of Journal Club at XXX research group, YYY Dep. - Task: pick topics, schedule talks, present papers, on a weekly basis. 10 participants.*

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it sound less like a book club or study group and more like group of colleagues? "Assumed an active leadership role" is more authoritative than coordinating and getting snacks. Drop co-coordinating as a verb. You don't have to toot the co-leaders horn in your CV. Scheduling and emailing sounds secretarial and website work sounds like an IT guy. You were a presenter before a group of colleagues or peers in this field on more than one occasion in an academic presentation series. A series of presentations on topics relating to X,Y, and Z. You put in the time and you deserve the accolade. Keep it professional and it doesn't have to say, "We were all grad students!" It sounds a like a series of talks and topics not unlike an academic continuing education conference except spread out over time. I hope you are feeling some of the potential phrasing you can use. Drop the part about the snacks, that's a given and plug in specifics about your presentation topics. Get your presentations and your name in the archive on that website.

Comment: "Can you make it sound less like a book club or study group and more like group of colleagues?"

Journal club is the accepted term for such a group. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_club